# Apache Derby/java db in jdk

Tags: java, derby

Does apache derby is included in IBM jdk and open jdk. Derby is included in oracle jdk as java db. If, can anybody share me the location.
If possible please refer a link or post.
Thanks

Comment: http://db.apache.org/derby/derby_downloads.html

Comment: thanks Scary. i want to know By default does derby is included in jdk's or not.

Comment: No, I believe that the JDK is just the interfaces and Derby is the reference implementation.

Comment: Because derby is referred as Javadb and included in oracle jdk 1.7 thatsy i am asking this and we can use the db using jdbc connection. Likewise i am asking for some other jdk's